# Problemas al reducir la velocidad de un objeto al colisionar con otro en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy desarrollando un videojuego en pygame y cuando el jugador colisiona con algo al principio si se detiene, pero si sigues manteniendo el botón en la dirrección del objeto, el jugador lo termina atravesando, lo extraño es que solo sucede si caminas pero si el jugador corre si se detiene de manera correcta, y la función de correr y la de caminar es la misma solo que con velocidades distintas (creo hay una manera mejor de que el jugador se mueva distintas velocidades sin básicamente una función pero primero quiero saber porque cuando el jugador corre si se detiene de manera correcta), he intentado usar los lados del rectángulo del objeto pero no me parece la manera mas adecuada considerando que varios de las imágenes que voy a usar no son rectangulares y se ve extraño, voy a insertar la función de detectar colisiones del jugador, y las funciones de movimiento del jugador y la función event del juego por si alguien encuentra el porque al correr el jugador si se detiene de manera adecuada

```
    def validate_colision(self, recurso):
        result = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, recurso)
        if result:
            if (recurso.pos_x > self.pos_x and self.vel_x > 0) or (recurso.pos_x < self.pos_x and self.vel_x < 0):
                self.vel_x *= 0
            elif (self.pos_y > recurso.pos_y and self.vel_y < 0) or (self.pos_y < recurso.pos_y and self.vel_y > 0):
                self.vel_y *= 0

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            self.player.vel_x = 0
            self.player.vel_y = 0

            if key[pygame.K_w] & key[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
                self.player.run(-2)
            elif key[pygame.K_w]:
                self.player.move(-2)
            elif key[pygame.K_s] & key[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
                self.player.run(2)
            elif key[pygame.K_s]:
                self.player.move(2)
            elif key[pygame.K_a] & key[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
                self.player.run(-1)
            elif key[pygame.K_a]:
                self.player.move(-1)
            elif key[pygame.K_d] & key[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
                self.player.run(1)
            elif key[pygame.K_d]:
                self.player.move(1)
```

**Actualización**

En un comentario me recomendaron que tratará de verificar si había un obstáculo en la dirección antes de avanzar, cosa que yo ya había intentado y con las cuales tuve problemas porque no sabia en que momento actualizar el valor que determinaba si había un obstáculo, ahora estoy intentado hacer algo como raycast como los que tienen los motores de juego que usado para ver como funciona eso junto con las máscaras para que sea más preciso, por ahora devuelve True si choca con algo, después probaré como funciona al momento de detener al jugador, pero por ahora funciona y no lo tengo que añadir a ningún grupo de sprite para que funcione, así colisiona sin que el jugador tenga que ver la línea hecha para que el collide_mask funcione

**Segunda Actualización**

Pues con el raycast tengo el mismo problema que tenía antes, no se cuando o como actualizar el valor para definir si está colisionando o no, si alguien conoce una manera de actualizar un valor sin hacerlo en el update sería de mucha ayuda

```
class Raycast(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self, player):
       super().__init__()
       self.player = player
       self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
       self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=self.player.rect.topleft)
       pygame.draw.line(self.image, YELLOW, (self.image.get_width()//2, self.image.get_height()//2), (self.image.get_width()//2 + 16, self.image.get_height()//2), self.player.image.get_height())
      self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
      self.collide = False

   def test_raycast(self, recurso):
       hit = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, recurso)
       if hit:
           self.collide = True

   def update(self): 
       self.rect.center = self.player.rect.center
       self.collide = False

   def move(self, value): #Función move del jugador
       if value == 1: #Solamente estoy probando el raycast hacia delante
          if not self.raycast.collide:
               self.vel_x += self.speed_x
```

**Tercera Actualización**

Descubrí como actualizar los valores en el update, y fue usando un valor del jugador que tuviera el mismo valor que el sprite.collide_mask y que si ese valor fuera None entonces el jugador pudiera avanzar, el problema ahora es que la colisión varía, si el jugador no se aleja mucho del objeto entonces la colisión será aún mas adentro del objeto y no se como solucionar eso porque no estoy seguro de como funciona el sprite_collide_mask

```
    def validate_colision(self, recurso):
        result = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, recurso)
        if result:
            if (recurso.pos_x > self.pos_x and self.vel_x > 0):
                self.front = True
        self.coll = result

    def update(self):
        if self.coll == None:
            self.front = False
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal si verificas que no tenga ningún obstáculo en la dirección que te quieres mover? Por lo que veo hasta ahora te mueves primero y te das cuenta cuando ya te chocaste.

Comment: @Mateo He intentado hacer algo así con colisión de mascaras, pero después tengo un problema similar porque hago que al colisionar las mascaras dependiendo de la dirección del objeto el jugador no se pueda mover a esa dirección con un booleano, pero no se en que momento actualizar ese valor porque si lo hago en el update termina atravasendo el objeto igual

Answer (score 0):

Si en tu juego el jugador atraviesa objetos al caminar pero no al correr, podría estar ocurriendo porque al caminar, la velocidad del jugador no se detiene adecuadamente cuando colisiona con un objeto. Para solucionar este problema, debes ajustar la lógica de colisión de manera que el jugador se detenga cuando choque con un objeto mientras camina.

En lugar de establecer la velocidad del jugador en 0 cuando colisiona, debes hacer que el jugador se detenga en el borde del objeto. Para lograr esto, verifica la dirección en la que se está moviendo el jugador (izquierda, derecha, arriba o abajo) y ajusta la posición del jugador para que se detenga justo en el borde del objeto en esa dirección. Esto evita que el jugador atraviese el objeto.

Asegúrate de que el tamaño del jugador y del objeto se tengan en cuenta adecuadamente en las operaciones de detección de colisiones para obtener el resultado deseado. Además, verifica que las velocidades de caminar y correr se estén aplicando correctamente en las funciones move y run.

```
def validate_colision(self, recurso):
result = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, recurso)
if result:
    if (recurso.pos_x > self.pos_x and self.vel_x > 0):
        self.pos_x = recurso.pos_x - self.width
    elif (recurso.pos_x < self.pos_x and self.vel_x < 0):
        self.pos_x = recurso.pos_x + recurso.width

    if (recurso.pos_y > self.pos_y and self.vel_y > 0):
        self.pos_y = recurso.pos_y - self.height
    elif (recurso.pos_y < self.pos_y and self.vel_y < 0):
        self.pos_y = recurso.pos_y + recurso.height
```

En esta modificación, se está ajustando la posición del jugador para que se detenga en el borde del objeto en función de la dirección en la que se está moviendo, lo que evita que el jugador atraviese el objeto al caminar. Asegúrate de que el tamaño del jugador y el objeto se tengan en cuenta correctamente en las operaciones de detección de colisiones.

**Correción de la respuesta**

El uso de máscaras de colisión en Pygame es útil cuando necesitas colisiones más precisas y no quieres depender únicamente de rectángulos para determinar las colisiones. Una máscara de colisión es una representación binaria de la forma de un objeto, lo que permite detectar colisiones basándose en la forma real del objeto en lugar de su rectángulo envolvente.

Primero, necesitas crear una máscara de colisión para tus objetos y luego utilizarla para detectar colisiones con la función collide_mask. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementar esto en tu código:

**1.-Crear una máscara de colisión para tus objetos:**

```
class Objeto(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, image_path):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert_alpha()
    self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

**2.-Modificar la función validate_colision para utilizar máscaras de colisión**

```
def validate_colision(self, recurso):
result = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, recurso)
if result:
    if (recurso.pos_x > self.pos_x and self.vel_x > 0) or (recurso.pos_x < self.pos_x and self.vel_x < 0):
        self.vel_x = 0

    if (recurso.pos_y > self.pos_y and self.vel_y > 0) or (recurso.pos_y < self.pos_y and self.vel_y < 0):
        self.vel_y = 0
```

Este código utiliza collide_mask en lugar de collide_rect para detectar colisiones entre dos objetos basándose en sus máscaras de colisión. Asegúrate de tener instalada la versión correcta de Pygame que incluye esta función (versión 2.0.0 o superior).

Con este enfoque, las colisiones serán más precisas y no dependerán del rectángulo envolvente de los objetos. Ten en cuenta que crear máscaras de colisión puede ser más costoso computacionalmente, especialmente si tienes muchos objetos en pantalla, por lo que debes equilibrar la precisión y el rendimiento según las necesidades de tu juego.

Comment: El problema con esta solución es que no se ve del todo bien porque si la persona mantiene presionado el botón de avanzar, pareciera como si se teletransportara y hace temblar todo, y además no todos los objetos que voy a usar son rectangulares y pos_x y pos_y se basa en el rectángulo del objeto, por eso prefiero encontrar una lógica que detenga al jugador sin depender del rectángulo del objeto. Y con tu corrección de las máscaras sigue sucediendo lo mismo, el jugador termina atravesando los objetos, el problema creo que esta en mi lógica para detener al jugador o al moverlo